# Position child DIV at the bottom of parent DIV

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I have gone through the questions that are already open, but couldn't find a resolution.

Its something like this:
......

```
      <div style="some height">
         <div style="some width"> .......and so on..
              ..

             <table>
                <tr>
                 <td>
                      <div id="parentDiv">
                         <div id="div1">Title Text and description.</div>
                         <div id="div2">Text+Image button here</div>
                      </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                     ..and more such columns and rows.
               </td>

          <Other divs closing>
```

Now, I want div2 to stick to the base of `parentDiv` all the time, irrespective of the height of `parentDiv`.

If I give position:relative to `parentDiv` and position:absolute to div2, I am not able to use and thing so that it sticks o the base of the `parentDiv`.

I want this because, if any other TD gets a bigger height due the content in div1, I want all the text and button image to stay aligned in a row.

P.S. - I cannot use a table inside a table to fix this problem as the actual scenario uses JS to feed a functionality. Any CSS to fix this issue?

Comment: What's the problem you're having using `position: absolute` and `position: relative`?

Answer (score 7):

Make `div2` `position: absolute` and then set `bottom: 0` on `div2`.

Just setting `position:absolute` on `div2` will not do the trick. For positioning it you will have to set `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` CSS properties. Setting `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0` ensures `div2`'s position is adjusted relative to closest ancestor that is non-static positioned (in this case, `parentDiv` which is `position: relative`).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but this will not work. bottom:0 doesn't make any difference to its current position, rather if you give bottom:1 you will observe that it goes upwards to 1px. Just gave it a fresh try.

Comment: Alright ! I got it working with the combination of the relative and absolute positions itself. It wasn't working for me earlier.. but its now ! Wierd, but it did :D

Absolute will take the closest parent relative position and use its boundaries as coordinates for placement.

Thanks you guys ! Problem solved.